# Calling unmanaged dll code from C++/CLI code throws SEHException immediately on any function call

Tags: .net, dll, c++-cli

I have the simplest possible unmanaged test dll that I just cannot call methods from using C++/CLI dll. I have the following code in the `NativeDll` project:

```
//TestFunctions.h
#pragma once

#ifdef NATIVEDLL_EXPORTS
#define NATIVE_FUNCTIONS_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#pragma comment(lib,"NativeDll.lib")
#define NATIVE_FUNCTIONS_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


extern "C" NATIVE_FUNCTIONS_API int test_function1();
extern "C" NATIVE_FUNCTIONS_API int test_function2();
```

Cpp file for the methods in the `NativeDll` project:

```
#include "TestFunctions.h"

int test_function1()
{
    return 1;
}
int test_function2()
{
    return 2;
}
```

In the calling C++/CLI `CompatLayer` dll project I'm calling the methods as follows:

```
//Compatibility.h
#pragma once

namespace CompatLayer {
    public ref class Compatibility
    {
    public:
        static void Initialize();
        static int f1();
        static int f2();
    };

}
```

Cpp file:

```
#include "Compatibility.h"
#include <TestFunctions.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

void CompatLayer::Compatibility::Initialize()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from compat layer init function!" << std::endl;
}

int CompatLayer::Compatibility::f1()
{
    try {
        std::cout << "Compat layer: Calling unmanaged code" << std::endl;//Prints fine
        return test_function1();
    }
    catch (System::Runtime::InteropServices::SEHException^ e) {//We always get SEHException
        std::cout << "SEHException thrown when calling unmanaged code" << std::endl;
        System::String^ msg = e->ToString();
        std::cout << msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(msg) << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception e) {
        std::cout << "std::exception thrown when executing code" << std::endl;
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

We are always getting the SEHException in the catch block in the C++/CLI code. The code in the `NativeDLL` project does not throw so I'm pretty much out of ideas where that exception could originate. Also the exception output isn't that useful:

```
SEHException thrown when calling unmanaged code
External component has thrown an exception.
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.
   at test_function1()
```

What could be causing this exception? It seems like the unmanaged code never gets invoked. Target .NET Framework is 4.0 and the native dll is marked as delay loading in the C++/CLI adapator dll.

Comment: Shouldn't the native functions in the `NativeDLL` project also use `NATIVE_FUNCTIONS_API` so as to be declared with `__declspec(dllexport)` ?

Comment: @MikeNakis the dll export comes from the header to the cpp source file. I just added that macro into the cpp file the same way it is used in the header file but with no differences whatso ever.

Comment: Right, I see, I missed that.

Comment: Broken exception handling code can be quite an obstacle to diagnose simple problems.  You can't see the SEHException.ErrorCode, so simple mishaps like not being able to find the unmanaged DLL gets to be hard to identify.  Golden rule is to not add try/catch until you understand what can go wrong and what you can do about it.

Comment: In the C# main project use Project > Properties > Debug tab > "Enable native code debugging" ticked.  Now you can get the debugger to stop at the exact moment the exception is thrown, Debug > Windows > Exception Settings > "Win32 exceptions" ticked.